# Ext Js and zeroclipboard

Tags: javascript, html, extjs, zeroclipboard

I have added an `actioncolumn` inside my grid. On the `actioncolumn` handler(click) I want to use the `zeroclipboard` library to copy the text to the clipboard.

I have encountered a few problems. Sometimes I need multiple clicks on my `actioncolumn` to trigger the copy. Sometimes I have to refresh the page to trigged the copy.

**My actioncolumn handler:**

```
handler: function(view, rowIndex, colIndex, item, e, record, row){

   ZeroClipboard.config({moviePath: 'resources/js/zeroclipboard/ZeroClipboard.swf'});
   var client = new ZeroClipboard(e.target);

   client.on('load',function(client) {

    client.on('datarequested', function(client) {
        client.setText("Text to be copied");
    });


    client.on('complete', function(client, args) {
       // alert("Copied text to clipboard: " + args.text);
       Myapp.app.getController('UiNotification').showNotification("Link copied to clipboard");
    });   
});
}
```

One of possible workarounds is to set the copy text on `mouseover` but the `actioncolumn` does not have any other events except the handler.

Please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the `actioncolumn` handler is a `click`? If so, then yes, dynamically attaching ZeroClipboard during a `click` event is too late. At best, it would be available during a 2nd click; at worst, it could be delayed several clicks (time-wise) as it also needs to asynchronously load the ZeroClipboard SWF file.

Comment: I figured this out but thanks anyway. I added the zeroclipboard to the renderer function..

Comment: @Jacob: Can you please provide a working example? That would be great.